# Why does the Promise chain work in this example, without throwing an error

Tags: javascript

So in the first example, the chain executes all the way to the last console.log, without an error, but in the second example, which is similar, it does error out. Why does this happen and can I somehow make the first example also throw an error?

I only know it has to do with adding functions to an object, because if `test` would be undefined, the chain would break, but I cannot understand how accessing a non-existant key in an object doesn't cause an error.

Edit: I just realized my brainfart. Naturally accessing `test.something` returns `undefined` instead of an error.

```js
// EXAMPLE 1: Weird

var test = {};

test.f1 = function(result) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("result", result);
        resolve(1)
    });
}

test.f2 = function(result) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("result", result);
        resolve(2)
    });
}

test.f3 = function(result) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("result", result);
        resolve(3)
    });
}

test.f4 = function(result) {
    console.log("result", result);
}

test.f1(1)
.then(test.f2)
.then(test.f3)
.then(test.shouldCauseError)
.then(test.f4)
```

```js
// EXAMPLE 2: As expected

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(1);
})
.then(function(result) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(2)
    });
})
.then(function(result) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(3)
    });
})
.then(shouldCauseError)
.then(function(result) {
    console.log("result:", result);
});
```

Comment: if you pass anything other than a function to .then, it is ignored - the reason for this is that .then can expect an onResolved and an onRejected callback, so, passing something other than a function to onresolved is ignored ... this is how promise/A+ spec is specified, since there is no `.catch` in the (original) specification ... `.catch(fn)` is simply `.then(null, fn)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.then` accepts up to two arguments. The first argument, *if it exists*, runs if the upper Promise resolved. The second argument, *if it exists*, runs if the upper Promise rejected.

Passing `undefined` as the first argument (or as both arguments) to `.then` is permitted - since no arguments exist, the upper Promise will be passed through the `.then` unchanged.

(also, `.then(undefined, fn)` is equivalent to `.catch(fn)`)

So, your

```
.then(test.shouldCauseError)
```

passes `undefined` to `.then`, which means that the upper Promise is passed through the `.then` *without modification* (and without throwing) - it goes to the next `.then` in the chain, as if `.then(test.shouldCauseError)` wasn't there.

Since passing `undefined` to `.then` is perfectly fine, you need some other method to create an error - perhaps wrap everything you pass to `.then`s in a function that checks if the passed expression is *actually* a function, and if not, returns a function that throws:

```
.then(validate(test.shouldCauseError))
```

```js
// EXAMPLE 1: Weird

var test = {};

test.f1 = function(result) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("result", result);
        resolve(1)
    });
}

test.f2 = function(result) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("result", result);
        resolve(2)
    });
}

test.f3 = function(result) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("result", result);
        resolve(3)
    });
}

test.f4 = function(result) {
    console.log("result", result);
}

const validate = arg => {
  if (typeof arg !== 'function') {
    return () => {
      throw new Error();
    }
  }
  return arg;
};

test.f1(1)
  .then(validate(test.f2))
  .then(validate(test.f3))
  .then(validate(test.shouldCauseError))
  .then(validate(test.f4))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error caught');
  });
```

You could also make `test` a Proxy that returns a throwing function when a property is accessed which doesn't exist on the target object.

But these are both *weird* solutions, because the "problem" being solved isn't considered a problem in JS. If you want to avoid these sorts of mistakes, I'd prefer to use something like Typescript to ensure that what I'm passing is of the right type, and not `undefined`.

Comment: Accepting your answer, because the `validate(...)` method is a good solution to the "problem" for me.

Answer (score 1):

In a `.then` listener, both arguments are **optional**. That is, the following is completely valid:

```js
Promise.resolve().then() //Nothing passed to then
```

Which is the same as if you write:

```js
Promise.resolve().then(undefined, undefined)
```

---

As accessing objects' non-existent properties return `undefined`, so...

```js
.then(test.shouldCauseError)
```

...is essentially the same as...

```js
.then(undefined)
```

...and it doesn't throw.

---

In the second case, however, it does throw, but it has nothing to do with `.then`: Accessing a non-existent *variable* throws a `ReferenceError`.

So the following also throws:

```js
shouldCauseError
```

...before `shouldCauseError`'s value could even be passed to `.then`